# Changing the JVM command line program in GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, profiling

I'm trying out the Link to Oracle Solaris Studio 12.2: Performance Analyzer
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1379/afabb.html

It requires you to use a `collect -j` command to run the `java` JVM.

Unfortunately, GlassFish appears to allow you to change only the Java home. In `./config/asenv.conf` there is an entry for `AS_JAVA`.

I tried to `start-domain` and capture the long Java command line there. However, it appears to hang.

Is there a way to change the JVM command line program? Hopefully, without hacking on the GlassFish scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No chance. You have to add the parameters to your asadmin script ... but this really isn't magic.